# Не инжектится ejb

Tags: java, servlet, ejb

Здравствуйте, у меня есть сервлет который работает и все отображает.
Он примерно такой

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.print("hello world");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Я перехожу по ссылке:  http://localhost:8080/test и вижу *hello world*

---

В другом пакете я создал такой Ejb:

```
import javax.ejb.*;

    @Stateless
    public class HelloWorldBean {

        public String sayHello() {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

Меняю код в сервлете, делаю его таким:

```
import javax.ejb.*;

@WebServlet("/test")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    HelloWorldBean worldBean;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.print(  worldBean.sayHello());
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

перехожу на http://localhost:8080/test и имею следующее :

```
Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class ru.company.MyServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Root Cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [ru.company.MyServlet/worldBean] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ru.company.MyServlet].
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:816)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.ForwardingInstanceManager.newInstance(ForwardingInstanceManager.java:26)
    org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.WeldForwardingInstanceManager.newInstance(WeldForwardingInstanceManager.java:71)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Помогите, почему вылезает такая ошибка?

Comment: Вы используете Tomcat?

Comment: да, и используется tomcat

Comment: Он не поддерживает EJB.

Comment: ааа, понял... Что-то не подумал об этом. Если сделаете в виде ответа, то можно закрыть вопрос )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat не поддерживает EJB. Используйте какой-нибудь сервер приложений - Glassfish, Wildfly и т.п. Если не хочется далеко отходить от знакомой платформы, можете попробовать TomEE.